# Laravel, Class controller does not exist in route with prefixes

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, lumen

Namespace in group (or callback) don't work (Lumen, Laravel)? I want to remove the code from routes.php to controllers. And so!

```
use App\Http\Controllers;

// OK!
$app->get('path', 'BarController@getId');

$app->group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function ($app) {
    // OK!
    $app->get('path', '\App\Http\Controllers\BarController@getId');

    // Class BarController does not exist
    $app->get('path', 'BarController@getId');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `use` statement to work, you'll have to use the `::class` syntax:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\BarController;

$app->get('path', BarController::class.'@getId');
```

Alternatively, you can add the namespace to your group:

```php
$app->group(['prefix' => 'foo', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('path', 'BarController@getId');
});
```

Comment: `BarController::class.'@getId'` - nope :(

Comment: `, 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'` - yep! tnx!